# chrome issue with javascript setDate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This very basic script creates 3 variables to use on pages, today date in a preferred format, a date +90 days from today and a date +120 days from today.

It works great on Firefox and IE, however in Chrome those variables come up as "undefined" and console outputs this:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'setDate'"

Here is my JavaScript

```
var today = new Date();
var rg = (today.getMonth()+1) + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();

var closed = new Date();
closed.setDate(today.getDate()+90);
var cl = (closed.getMonth()+1) + "/" + closed.getDate() + "/" + closed.getFullYear();

var expire = new Date();
expire.setDate(today.getDate()+120);
var ex = (expire.getMonth()+1) + "/" + expire.getDate() + "/" + expire.getFullYear();
```

Comment: It appears to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jf4Vv/) in Chrome. If it doesn't work for you there, what version of Chrome on are you on?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'setDate" --- for which line?

Comment: Works in Chrome for me (on both Mac OS and Windows.)

Comment: Error comes up on the line 5. So the first variable actually works, but  the second and third ones don't.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus - I also tested on jsfiddle - and it does work. Its a great site, thanks. So what can be causing the issue on my work site????

Comment: @SvetlanaBiscornet Check my answer below. It works on jsFiddle because it uses an `iframe` to run the code (so the scope doesn't have `closed` reserved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closed` is a reserved name for any `window` objects. (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.closed)) Since you're running this in the global space all variables are stored underneath `window`, so you're running into collision with what the browser thinks `window.closed` should be.

Simply change `var closed = new Date();` to a new name or as @KingKongFrog suggests place it in a new scope via a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Place this in an anonymous function and try

```
(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var rg = (today.getMonth()+1) + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();

    var closed = new Date();
    closed.setDate(today.getDate()+90);
    var cl = (closed.getMonth()+1) + "/" + closed.getDate() + "/" + closed.getFullYear();

    var expire = new Date();
    expire.setDate(today.getDate()+120);
    var ex = (expire.getMonth()+1) + "/" + expire.getDate() + "/" + expire.getFullYear();
})();
```